# How to create a "lookup column" in Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-access, mapping, lookup

In Microsoft Access, we can easily create a "lookup column", that has one type of saved internal data (L, M, S labels below) automatically mapped to some different dynamic display data (Large, Medium, and Small labels).

[image]

All it takes in Access is some easy table column design configuration:

[image]

Is it possible to have something similar in Microsoft Excel? With no separate lookup tables connected through VLOOKUP, or additional columns. Something as simple as in Access, with some immediate value mapping. With the loaded column cells having one value but displaying one different mapped value.

Comment: AFAIK, must refer to a list on a sheet, and no alias. See documentation https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-list-box-or-combo-box-to-a-worksheet-in-excel-579e1958-f7f6-41ae-ba0c-c83cc6e40878

Comment: "... no separate lookup tables connected.. " hardcode it.  >> Eg. (put in B1) `=IFERROR(INDEX({"Large","Medium","Small"},MATCH(A1,{"L","M","S"},0)),"")`